# Adjectival form of "library"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, adjectives

I can only think of *librarily* and *librarish*. Can I use those? Are there other better alternatives?

Example:

> The topic of this book isn't very "[...]". I don't think you should
>   donate it.

Comment: Please provide the context of how you intend to use the word.

Comment: @AndrewLeach OK, done.

Comment: I think something like *suitable* would fit there. Or maybe "suitable for the library".

Comment: **Archival** isn't quite what you want, but the sentence could be reworked to make it fit.

Comment: "The topic of this book isn't very library-appropriate"? Alternatively, if it's an informal setting, I like the idea of just italicizing: "The topic of this book isn't very *library*." That's how I would say it in everyday speech.

Comment: There is [bibliothecal](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bibliothecal) but it is not a very useful word and it doesn't fit to your sentence.

Comment: The problem with your question is that it is not at all clear what the characteristic is that you think makes a book suitable or unsuitable for a library. In principle, libraries can carry books of every kind (though obviously some of them specialize in certain subject areas, such a law library or medical library). So unless you clarify the focus of the question, nobody will be able to give you a useful response.

Comment: The characteristics are probably context-dependent. You wouldn't donate porn to a children's library (I suspect most public libraries wouldn't want it, either, although the threshold for what they consider pornographic might be different).

Answer (score 1):

**librarial**

It seemed like the natural option to me, and when I searched for it I found it in at least [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/librarial) and the [Urban dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Librarial+Complex). It is rare though, and Google only has about 5000 pages in total for it. Wiktionary notes that it is more common to use *library* as an attributive noun.

Answer (score 0):

"The topic of this book isn't very library friendly?"

Answer (score 0):

**Bibliothecal**--(adj) Relating to a bibliotheca (library). CollinsDictionary.com

Comment: Fun answer. Maybe they'll stick around to find a dictionary and look that one up. :)

Answer (score -2):

What about *Libraic*, or might that refer to the base word *libra*? (i.e., etymologically Latin 'libra' vs. 'liber')